# How do I advertise routes from a non-OSPF network into OSPF networks

Tags: networking, cisco, ospf

I have the following configuration

[image]

I have routers R6, R8, R9, R10 and R11 running OSPF. And routers R12, R13 and host C1 aren't. C1 has its default gateway set to R13's shared interface and R13 and R12 have their default gateways set to R6's interface with them.

Now, I'd like to ping a host connected to R11 from C1. The problem I have is that none of the routers running OSPF can see the network C1-R12-R13. The only network in that area I can see from any of them is the one shared by R6-R12-R13.

How can I make that other network known to the routers running OSPF?

Thanks

Comment: What's your use case here? This seems like a very odd configuration. What  type of environment are running that requires this? Can you provide device models and configuration snippets?

Comment: @EEAA It's a simplification of the model I'm using, actually. Unfortunately, I can't show you the exact configuration due to confidentiality. I can tell you the routers are C3600, and the switch is an Ethernet switch. All running Cisco IOS

Comment: You sure this isn't another homework question?

Answer (score 1):

If R6 has the route to the network you want, then `redistribute static` should work, inside R6 OSPF configuration.

You can add a route map if you want, to redistribute only the network you want into OSPF.

A *simplest* solution would be to run OSPF everywhere.